# Select a list , and update the records one by one according to some field.How to avoid duplicate update?

Tags: java, sql, transactions, spring-data-jpa, currency

Select a list and update the records one by one according to some field value .How to avoid duplicate update and insert ?

```
public void takeOrder(String currentUser){
   String sql = "select * from customer where take_status is null limit 30";
   List<Customer> customerList = customerDao.findUnTakeCustomer(sql);
   for(Customer cust : customerList){
     if(cust.getEntryId > 3){
        cust.setTakeStatus(1);
        update(cust);
        Sd sd = new Sd();
        sd.setUser(currentUser);
        sd.setCust(cust);
        sd.setTakeTime(new Date());
        sdDao.save(sd);
     }
   }
}
```

If two user take order at the same time , the customerList maybe have same records,  then duplicate record will be insert into table SD ,and the customer record will be update twice!

How to avoid this ?

Answer (score 0):

use a primary key in your mysql.

```
create table tablename(
     yourPrimaryKey int(10),
     otherColumns   varchar(10),

     primary key(yourPrimaryKey)
);
```

primary key will be your unique code for every transaction. just like receipt number in any convenient store

Comment: Yes ! If I set customer_id in SD to unique,it works.
But to be compatible with history data and logic, I cannot do that ! Do you know some other solutions just through using java code,other than database constraint  ？

Comment: @footoss will you please site an example of what history data and logic? maybe you did not make your main primary key as parent to other table columns..

example:

you have table receipt( 
                receipt_no int(10)

Comment: @footoss will you please site an example of what history data and logic? maybe u didnt make your main primary key as parent to other table columns.

example:

you have 
create table receipt( 
                receipt_no int(10),
                primary key(receipt_no));

create table receipt_info(
                 receipt_no int(10),
                 items        varchar(50),
                 primary key (receipt_no));

looking into that example you have 2 receipt_no. that the parent will be in the table receipt. better foreign key the receipt_info.receipt_no to receipt.receipt_no